# how to find if std::deque holds given object?

Tags: c++, deque

I have a `container<std::deque<T>>` and a `const T*ptr` which I know points to an object in one of the contained `deque`s. Now, I like to know (1) which `deque` it comes from and (2) its index in that one. How to get that info?

I'm aware that I can iterate over all objects, but there ought to be a faster solution, ought it not?

Comment: I don't know how you got into that corner, but the best solution is most probably to refactor the original problem to avoid this situation. There are a couple of red flags here, for example, insertions or removals in the middle of the `deque` can change the object your pointer refers to (conceptually using *the object* as the object holding the value you expect)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I use the `deque`s as threadlocal allocators for temporary objects. I only `emplace()` them at the end and hence never invalidate any previous pointers.

Comment: ... and for some reason you don't know which thread allocated the object? Does this not mean that a different thread might be trying to deallocate/act on the object and thus the object is really *shared* and not *thread-local* (conceptually)? If you do know the thread, then you should know which of the `deque` holds the value, right?

Comment: The objects are threadlocally allocated and used, but in another phase of the algorithm, they are shared. They live as long as the `container<std::deque<T>>` does. The `container` is essentially a (threadsafe version of) `map<thread::id,std::deque<T>>`.

Comment: If at a later time different threads access the same object, then you cannot consider the `deque` to be thread-local. Consider creating the objects dynamically and passing ownership of the pointer around. That way the `deque` use will be accessed by a single thread. Otherwise you will always have multiple threads accessing the same `deque` data structure.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas the same object won't be accessed by more than one thread, but possibly by a different thread than the one that created it.

Answer (score 0):

That's a task for a double iteration:

1. iterate over container
2. iterate over current element (a deque) and compare

#

```
template<typename container> std::pair<container::iterator_t, size_t> FindIndices(const container& c, const container::value_type* x) {
    for(auto a = c.begin(); a != c.end(); a++)
        for(auto b = a->begin(); b != a->end(); b++)
            if(&*b == x)
                return std::pair<container::iterator_t, size_t>(a, b-a->begin());
    return std::pair<container::iterator_t, size_t>(c.end(), -1);
}
```

If you can instead store shared_pointers or unique_pointers in your container, you can use a std::map to efficiently retrieve the indices, as long as those don't change.
If only the queue does not change, then there is still some potential for savings.

Comment: +1 for the first three lines. The last line is wrong, you cannot use the address of the *stored* object as the key in a map, as to insert it you need the key, and you cannot get the address of the inserted element until *after* it has been inserted.

Comment: The trouble is probably not that you don't get the address until after insertion, but that additional insertion would invalidate it. Same effect though, so i removed it.

Comment: Well, pointers and references into a `std::map` are stable (never change from insertion until removal)

Answer (score 0):

Something like (and I havent compiled this but you get the idea):

```
container<deque<T>> MyCont;
for( auto iter = MyCont.begin(); iter != MyCont.end(); ++iter )
{
  auto foundIter = find( *iter.begin(), *iter.end(), MyObject );
  if ( foundIter != *iter.end() )
  {
    dequeIndex = distance( *iter.begin(), foundIter );
    containerIndex = distance( MyCont.begin(), iter );
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: The `find` algorithm will find an object with the same *value*, not the same object (i.e. not the object with the given address). For that you would have to use `std::find_if` with a predicate that checks identity. Other than that, the `std::distance` algorithm takes two iterators, not a value and an iterator (`*iter.begin()`), and you can get away without the second call to `distance` by tracking the count in the outer loop (and without the previous call by using a loop instead of `find`...)

Comment: So, there is no faster solution than to iterate over all objects?

Comment: @Walter: Not if you need the same object. Unless you have more guarantees. You could store pointers instead of the object though, allowing you to use a std::map.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I misread the code. I thought the deque<T> was of pointers and assumed he was looking for the exact object not one that is equivalent. The distance is being passed two iterators as it should. You are also correct that one distance can be gotten rid of by adding a counter.

Comment: @qeadz: Uhm.. I misread the code, but it is wrong anyways. You mean to do `iter->begin()` (or `(*iter).begin()`, not `*iter.begin()`. I read `*XXX.begin()` that is dereferencing the result of a call to `begin()`, and thus dereferencing an iterator.